# How to pass javascript variables to rails variables

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

How can I pass a javaScript variable into ruby. I want to do something like this but I don't know how to express it.

```
function save(){
    var g = document.getElementById("self").value;
    <% @owner.info = g %>
}
```

Another possible work around is that i would need to be able to extract contents of a text area through rails and not javascript.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Doing the opposite of what you want (ruby variable to javascript) is very possible. What you're trying to do is... complicated. With rails, javascript executes in a browser, and ruby runs on a VM on your server. You can run nodejs on the server and pass it over to your ruby app, but I'm thinking that's not actually what you want to do. Please clarify the overall scenario you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: Each user has an account and they have a piece of information that says something about themselves. When they hit save I am getting javascript to pull what they said but then i need to transfer it over to ruby to store in the database. I have been using form_for to do this task in the past but i've always redirected the user to another page and i don't want to do that now. I have a small area on my page where the information is displayed. I am thinking of just squeezing a form_for in that spot and not have to deal with javascript at all. do you think that is better?

Comment: Ok, so what you'll really want to do here is send an ajax request to the server to save the data without the user leaving the page. This guide gives a good overview: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Comment: I compiled my comments into an answer and added a few notes about where ruby code vs. javascript is exectued

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting to do doesn't make sense with a vanilla rails installation and javascript. Here's a good workflow that accomplishes what you're trying to do along with some details:

#### 1. A page is requested from the server

The ruby code that runs rails and your application is executed on the server. The server receives a request, executes the ruby code, and sends the response as an html document.

#### 2. A user gets the response from the server

The user's browser receives the html and turns it into a pretty web page. It's at this point that any javascript related to your application is executed in the user's browser. The connection with the server has been severed and no further ruby code will be executed until another request is made.

#### 3. The user fills out an ajax form

On the page rendered in step 2, you have a form. Following [this guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) you can tell this form to submit via ajax. That means instead of requesting a new web page, the browser will send a special request using javascript to the server. The server can save the form values to your database and send a response back to the browser. All the while the user hasn't left the page they are currently viewing.

Alternatively you can skip the ajax and have the user submit the form, but you'll need to redirect them back to the page they were viewing (and probably adding a note the form they submitted was saved).